# Find the maximum value of $2x-4x^2 > 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$x \in \mathbb{R}$.

**My attempt:**

We’re gonna check the case where: $2x-4x^2 >0$.

And by some basic algebra you will find that : $$ x \in ]0,\frac{1}{2}[$$
But since we are in Real numbers we can’t just plug numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**

Use the canonical form ;
$$f(x)=-(4x^2-2x)$$
$$=\frac 14-(2x-\frac 12)^2$$

$$\le \frac 14$$

Comment: Then the Maximum value is$$ \frac{1}{4}$$??

Comment: M3loum. $max f(x)=\frac 14$ attained at $ x=\frac 14$.

Answer (score 2):

Using the AM-GM [inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), given $2x-4x^2>0$,

$\sqrt{2x-4x^2 }=\sqrt{2x(1-2x)}\le\dfrac{(2x)+(1-2x)}2=\dfrac12$.

Now square both sides.

Comment: Hi Pennsylvanian man. smart answer (+1).

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah:  I just gave you $+1$ too; your answer is what I was originally going to post, but you beat me to it

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = 2x-4x^{2} \implies f'(x)=2-8x$.

Note that $f(x)$ is represented graphically as a downward facing parabola because of the sign of the coefficient of the $x^{2}$ term.

Hence, finding when the slope is $0$ we have the maximum when the value is valid.

Setting $f'(x) =0$ we have $8x=2 \implies x = 
\frac{1}{4}$ which is in the interval you found.